# What is the image near the essential singularity $z=0$ of $\cos(1/z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series, singularity-theory

Determine the image  near the essential singularity $z=0$ of the function $\cos(1/z)$. i.e. if $f(z)=\cos(1/z)$, What is $f\left(\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(0)\right)$ for $\varepsilon > 0$?

**Remark:** I know that the image near the essential singularity $z=0$ of $e^{1/z}$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{0\right\}$, but not how to use it to prove this statement.

Comment: Do you know why $0$ is an essential singularity of $cos(\frac{1}{z})$ or do you want to see this as well?

Comment: Because then you can use Picard's theorem, which provides that the image of $B_\epsilon(0)\setminus\{0\}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ with one possible point as potential exception.

Comment: @johnnycrab In the course that I am studyind we have seen Picard's Theorem

Comment: So do you need help applying Picard's Theorem (i.e. if the image is whole $\mathbb{C}$, or if there's a point that's missing), or do you need help to prove that $0$ is an essential singularity?

Answer (score 2):

Picard, really? Come now good people, we're talking about your friend the cosine. First, you do not mean $B_\epsilon(0).$ You mean $\{0<|z|<\epsilon\}.$ Second, where does $1/z$ send $\{0<|z|<\epsilon\}?$ It sends it to $\{1/\epsilon<|z|<\infty\}.$ And where does $\cos $ take this set to? Well, $\cos $ is $2\pi$-periodic. And $\{1/\epsilon<|z|<\infty\}$ contains plenty of vertical strips that are $2\pi$ wide in length. Therefore $\cos (1/z)$ takes $\{0<|z|<\epsilon\}$ onto $\cos (\mathbb C).$ So the answer is $\cos (\mathbb C).$ Figure that out, and you're done. (Spoiler: $\cos (\mathbb C) =\mathbb C.$)

Answer (score 1):

$$
 \cos \left( z^{-1} \right) 
$$
Re: blue, Im: red.

[image: conformal]